# I keep getting an incompatible type error

Tags: java

I am trying to write a password program and keep getting an incompatible type error. Here's the part of the program that is supposed to check for special characters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordValidator{
  public static void main(String[]args){

    String pass;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter desired password");
    pass = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(pass.length()>=8&&
       pass.length()<=15){
    System.out.println("Valid");}
    else{ System.out.println("INVALID! Password must contain between 8 to 15 characters!");}
    if (pass.contains("!@#")){
       System.out.println("Valid");}
    else { System.out.println("INVALID! Password must contain special character!");}
    if(pass.charAt(0));{
      System.out.println("INVALID! Password cannot begin with special characters!");}
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error on `if(pass.charAt(0));`

It says I have an incompatible type and requires boolean not char.

Comment: You need to compare the char to something.

Comment: The error message is telling you **exactly** what's wrong. What is the meaning of `if ('c')` anyway? That is a nonsense statement. You need `if (myChar == otherChar)` or something like that -- a true/false statement. The most important message in this is to read the error messages with a critical eye as they usually tell you exactly what you're doing wrong, just like it's doing here.